# Cannot resolve symbol useParams

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, webstorm, react-router-dom

I'm creating an app with react in using WebStorm. I am attempting to use react-router-dom useParams. I have react-router-dom 5.1.2 as a dependency, but useParams is grayed out in import statement. When I hover over useParams it says "Cannot resolve symbol useParams". I am also trying to import Switch and i'm receiving a similar message "Cannot resolve symbol Switch". What's even more unusual is Link is being imported from react-router-dom.

[image] [image][image]

Comment: Just curious, does it still compile and run? Is it just intellisense not picking it up?

Comment: @AlexK it runs but crashes when I click on any product link. Also, when console log thisProduct it returns undefined

Comment: That's strange, nothing stands out from those images, do you have a repro you can provide from codesandbox or something similar?

Comment: @AlexK i made a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-chandrasekhar-sjibs

Comment: @user3574939 Your .find() is failing because `productId` from the route params is a string where your ids in your data are numbers. You need to convert productId to a number (multiple ways to do that, I used a `+`), I forked and corrected your sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-elbakyan-k07qc

Comment: Whenever you use a `.find()` it's a good idea to handle the case where it doesn't return a value since it can always potentially return `undefined` to prevent the entire app from crashing.

Answer (score 14):

`node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js` re-exports `Switch`, `Root`, `useParams` from `react-router`. But the latter is not listed as a direct dependency in your `package.json` and thus is excluded from indexing.
You can un-exclude it by choosing **Mark Directory as/Not excluded** from `node_modules/react-router` right-click menu:

[image]

But I'd strongly recommend installing Typescript stubs for the package for better completion/type hinting instead: put cursor on `"react-router-dom"` in import statement, hit `Alt+Enter`, choose **Install TypeScript definitions for better type information**

[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

Comment: what does "Install TypeScript definitions for better type information" do exactly ? Because I don't see anything added to package.json.

Comment: it is not supposed to add anything there; d.ts files are downloaded to IDE configuration folder and added to your project as a library, only available to the IDE. If you like typings to be downloaded in your project and added to package.json, run `npm i @types/react-router-dom` command in terminal

Answer (score 5):

I was encountering the same issue in 2020.1. I didn't have the `Alt+Enter` option of installing TypeScript definitions. I had to go to **File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries** and **Download...** `@types/react-router` to make the warning go away. I never would have thought to download the `react-router` types if it weren't for lena's answer.

[image]

[image]

The list is a little daunting because at first glance it looks like you have to scroll through it, but, if you click on one of the entries and start typing, a search box should appear.

Answer (score 1):

Beside of adding proper library you need to add proper scope for your project.

1. Downlaod required libraries.
2. Double check if they are in proper scope.

[image: please take a look at image]

Comment: How does this help? What do you suggest I change it to? I'sn't it fine how it is by default?

Comment: In my case after installation of libraries it was not part of the project scope, so I needed to ad t manually, most probobly it should be added automatically, just want to point additional steps, that could be take if someone run into similar issue.